# How can I prove that $\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} \rightrightarrows |x|$?

Tags: calculus

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}}.$$ I am trying to show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to the absolute value function $x \mapsto |x|$.

My idea is to first show that composition with a uniformly continuous function preserves uniform convergence. That is, if $(f_n) \rightrightarrows f$ and $g$ is uniformly continuous then $$g \circ f_n \rightrightarrows g \circ f.$$
Uniform continuity of $g$ provides a $\delta > 0$ for which $$|x - t| < \delta \Rightarrow |g(x) - g(t)| < \epsilon.$$ Then uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ implies that $$|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \delta$$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, and for all $x$, and so we have that $$|g(f_n(x)) - g(f(x))| < \epsilon.$$

Then since $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, it is uniformly continuous, and clearly $x^2 + \frac{1}{n} \rightrightarrows x^2$ by choosing $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon$.

Another strategy I thought of might be to show that $|\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} - \sqrt{x^2}|$ attains a maximum at $x = 0$. That way I could bound the difference by $1/\sqrt{n}$. Unfortunately, I can't just differentiate the difference and show that it increases as $x \to 0$ because $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: This is a straightfoward application of Dini's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$$|x|<\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}<|x|+\frac1{\sqrt n}$$ so $f_n(x)\to|x|$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} - \sqrt{x^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{x^2}} \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: on showing the maximum you can use the property

$$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$$

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$g_n(x)=f_n(x)-|x|$$

$g_n$ is an even function.

At $ [0,1] $,

$$g'_n(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac 1n}}-1$$

$$=-\frac 1n\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac 1n}\Bigl(x+\sqrt{x^2+\frac 1n}\Bigr)}<0$$

the maximum of $ g_n$ is
$$g_n(0)=\sqrt{\frac 1n}$$
it goes to zero, then the convergence is uniform at $ [-1,1].$

Comment: Just to clarify: don't you need that $g_n$ is differentiable at $0$ to conclude that it increases on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Sorry I meant "decreasing" in my comment above. Continuity of $g_n$ on $[0,1]$ implies that $g_n$ attains a maximum on $[0,1]$. Since $g_n$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and $g_n'(x) < 0$, $g_n(x_1) > g_n(x_2)$ whenever $x_1 < x_2$. I believe you can derive a contradiction from the assumption that $g_n(0)$ is not the maximum.

Comment: @yonatano $g_n$ is even, so you just need the max at $[0,1]$,